# Parse number until comma

Tags: c++, parsing

I have a format where, in a string, `88` is to be parsed as the number 88 while `8,8` is to be parsed as two 8s. I need to go through the string, and for every `.`, push a 0 to a vector, and otherwise push the number(s) at the current position to the vector according to the above rule. Zeros will never appear in the input string. I don't want to use yacc or another BNF parser generator; it would be overkill for my situation. What's the easiest way to do this? Here's what I've go so far; it's only partial and doesn't even compile:

```
for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++){
  if (line[i] == '.')
    puzzle.push_back(0);
  else
    //do weird comma stuff
    //push stuff
}
```

Example:

`line = ".1.1,1.11"
puzzle = {0,1,0,1,1,0,11}`

Comment: `line` is your input, but what is actually your output? You talk both about a comma and a point. It's a bit confusing. Please provide a relevant input example and a desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch what it looks like you're asking for (not compiled, not tested):

```
int value;
bool in_number = false;
while (cin.getline(line)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); ++i)
        switch(line[i]) {
            case '.':
                if (in_number) {
                    puzzle.push_back(value);
                    in_number = false;
                }
                puzzle.push_back(0);
                break;
            case ',':
                if (in_number) {
                    puzzle.push_back(value);
                    in_number = false;
                }
                break;
            case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
            case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
                if (in_number) {
                    value *= 10;
                    value += line[i] - '0';
                } else {
                    in_number = true;
                    value = line[i] - '0';
                }
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Can't you replace `case '0': case '1' ...` with `if (line[i] >= '0' && line[i] <= '9')`

Comment: @RenéG - yes, in an `if ... else if ... ` ladder. Not in a switch. For a lexer like this I prefer a switch statement, with a function to classify the input. But an `if ... else if ...` ladder would also work

Comment: Or use `isdigit()` to detect the digit?  Looks like an if-else-if ladder may be more efficient (or easier to maintain).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - of course, "efficient" needs measurement, but it's not at all obvious that calling a function to determine whether a character is a digit is faster than having the compiler generate code that does it. I'd bet on it being the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

For such tasks common solution is to use regexp:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::string s(".1.1,1.11");
  std::smatch m;
  std::regex e("([0-9]+|\\.)[,]?");  
  std::vector<int> v;
  while (std::regex_search(s, m, e)) {
    const std::string& d = m[1];
    v.push_back(strtol(d.c_str(), 0, 10));
    s = m.suffix().str();
  }
  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AntolyS's answer is probably cleanest, but I went with a modified version of Pete Becker's answer because I'm a noob and there were to many weird things going on with Antoly's:

```
 int value; bool in_number = false;
 for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++){
    if (line[i] == '.'){
      if (in_number){
    puzzle.push_back(value);
    in_number = false;
      }
      puzzle.push_back(0);
    }
    else if (line[i] == ','){
      if (in_number) {
    puzzle.push_back(value);
    in_number = false;
      }
    }
    else if (line[i] > '0' && line[i] <= '9'){
      if (in_number) {
    value *= 10;
    value += line[i] - '0';
      } else {
    in_number = true;
    value = line[i] - '0';
      }
    }
 }
```